# How to get rid of "Unrecognized option: --module-path" error in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jvm

I am getting the following error when i run my JavaFX project.

[image]

This is my eclipse.ini file

[image]

Run Configuration of this project

[image: Run configuration Image]

This is the command used for VM arguemnts:
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

I have updated my eclipse from 2019-3 to 2020-12. Is there anything that i need to modify in eclipse.ini file?

I am using the following versions of libraries and IDE

Eclipse 2020-12

JDK 15

JavaFX 15.0.1

e(fx)clipse 3.6.0

I am new to this JavaFX. I have tried so many solutions explained in youtube and google but I couldn't overcome this error. I hope i could find an answer here.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run your application with JDK 8 or earlier. (The actual path you provide as the module path looks wrong too.)

Comment: Why do you have both the javafx and the swingbuilder tags?

Comment: The `eclipse.ini` is to run Eclipse and not used for running your application (delete the first `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` line as it must be a line after and not before `-vmargs`). Show your run configuration and what the _Show Command Line_ button tells.

Comment: no screenshots of text, please ... simply c&p

Comment: Please, please show screenshots! You might included it as text in addition, but without the screenshots it would be unclear what you have where. @kleopatra

Comment: @howlger please read my comment carefully ;) The ini file clearly is text only, so there is absolutely no reason to add it as unreadable and unsearchable image!

Comment: You should not enter _VM arguments_ here. Everything has to be configured in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_. Currently, you have configured Java 8 for the projects that conflicts with the entered VM arguments in the run configuration.

Comment: @kleopatra See my previous comment to understand that removing the screenshots would have prevented being able to help here. I'm using [Capture2Text](http://capture2text.sourceforge.net/) for OCR when needed. You might consider doing the same. For what reason do you need the ini file as text?

Comment: @howlger ehh .. how would any text recognition help when searching this site? Anyway,  the help pages clearly state that screenshots of __TEXT__ (as f.i. the ini file and the error message, the combined context setup is okay, IMO) are unwanted, so newbies should be made aware of it. *off

Comment: @kleopatra The ini file is not relevant here as image, as text and searchable. The other screenshots provide important information. It is unclear which one(s) your comment refers to. What I'm missing here from your side is [our expectations](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#expectations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my JRE version from 1.8.0_171 to 1.8.0_281

And I have rectified my VM arguments path too

--module-path "E:\eclipse\ *javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib*" --add-modules **=** javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Now It's working fine;)

P.S: Please refer to this [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction) document for clear understanding.

Comment: Still `Unrecognized option: --module-path` even after upgrading Java to build 1.8.0_282-b08.

Comment: In my case, I had to download the JavaFX SDK and then specify the JavaFX SDK path as "module-path" and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Modules were introduced in Java 9.

Reference: https://www.oracle.com/br/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html